# MongoDB $lookup not working properly with nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I checked some document and I prepared the below query its not working as expected its comming direct child of SubProject with empty array. But Its working with Mongodb 6 but not in lower version 5.

This is my code:

```
await SubProduct.aggregate([
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "products",
                        localField: "productID",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "product_Details"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $unwind: "$product_Details"
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "users",
                        localField: "product_Details.userId",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "user_Details"
                    }
                },{
                    $project: {
                        "user_Details.password": 0
                    }
                }
            ]);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
        "name": "kkkk",
        "phoneNum": 9543922499,
        "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
        "address": {
            "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
            "zipCode": 6250185
        },
        "product_Details": {
            "_id": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
            "name": "lu",
            "price": "123",
            "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
        },
        "user_Details": []
    }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "643d7ed82cd5b5fcd7e81e02",
    "address": {
      "address1": "243, bastin nagarsss",
      "zipCode": 6.250185e+06
    },
    "name": "kkkk",
    "phoneNum": 9.543922499e+09,
    "productID": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
    "product_Details": [
      {
        "_id": "643bbdee68b521035e20c976",
        "isActive": true,
        "name": "lu",
        "price": 123,
        "userId": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
        "user_Details": [
          {
            "_id": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7",
            "name": "Rituparna Warwatkar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "user": "643abd0dcce4df3b1a0c8fa7"
  }
]
```

If I used version 6 I'm getting expected output but in version 5 its not working. I need to know how multilevel achieved through lookups

Comment: why userdetails empty array in first. anyway if not empty can do something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtCrCVLoEGV)